# Deleting Items from my ReactJs Shopping Cart Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, cart

So I'm making a shopping cart, and I want to be able to delete things from my cart. I can add the values without any problem, but they won't delete for some reason. Here is my code:

```
   function addToCart(e) {
  var updatedCart = { ...cart };
  if (!updatedCart[e.target.textContent]) {
    updatedCart[e.target.textContent] = 1;
  } else {
    updatedCart[e.target.textContent] += 1;
  }
  setCart(updatedCart);
}
function removeItem(item) {
  var cartCopy = {...cart}
  delete cartCopy[item]
  setCart(cartCopy)
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it give you an error? Or just doesn't delete?

Comment: @Sinan Yaman it just doesn't delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function removeItem(item) {
   const cardCopy = Object.entries(cart).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
     return key !== item ? {...acc, [key]: value} : acc;
   }, {})
   setCart(cardCopy)
  }
```

Comment: what do I need to pass as item?

Comment: nevermind, it works now. Many thanks. Happy new year in advance.